# Customizing whole Apache Superset UI

Tags: apache-superset

In Superset one can customize the styles for a particular dashboard through CSS-templates, but I want to change the styles for the whole UI such as Home page on which you see the list of dashboards. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Also wondering the same thing. Have you found any solution yet?